# Запросы в React

Tags: reactjs, redux, хук

Делаю приложение, в actions имеется такой запрос:

```
export function fetchFlights() {
    return async(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(filterHandler())

        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/flights.json'

        try {
            await axios.get(url).then(data => {
                const response = data.data.result.flights
                dispatch(pushFlights(response))
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }      
}
```

Если в него особо не вникать, я просто получаю данные из JSON и сохраняю их в State. Далее, я пытаюсь вывести их в компонент:

```
import "./Flight.css"
import { fetchFlights } from "../../store/actions/actions"
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { useEffect } from "react"


const Flight = props => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchFlights())
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ width: '100%', padding: '5px 10px' }}>
                <span style={{color: '#1E90FF'}}>
                    { props.result[0].flight.legs[0].segments[0].departureCity.caption },&nbsp;
                    { props.result[0].flight.legs[0].segments[0].departureAirport.caption }
                    <span style={{fontSize: 20, padding: "0 15px 0 15px"}}>→ </span>
                </span> 
                <span style={{color: '#1E90FF'}}>
                    { props.result[0].flight.legs[0].segments[0].arrivalAirport.caption }
                </span>
                <hr style={{opacity: .3}}/>
            </div>
            <div className="Time">
                <div>
                    <span style={{fontSize: 23, color: '#000'}}>
                        18:10
                    </span> 
                    <span style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#1E90FF', paddingLeft: 20}}>
                        19 авг. ср
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div style={{fontSize: 23, margin: '0 auto', color: "#000"}}>
                    &#9719; 3 ч 35 мин
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#1E90FF', paddingRight: 20}}>
                        19 авг. ср 
                    </span> 
                    <span style={{fontSize: 23, color: '#000'}}>
                        21:45
                    </span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="hrSect">
                    <span style={{color: '#FF8C00'}}>1 пересадка</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p style={{padding: "0px 10px", color: "#000"}}>
                    Рейс выполняет: {props.result[0].flight.carrier.caption}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        result: state.result
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchFlights: () => dispatch(fetchFlights())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Flight)
```

Однако я получаю undefined (то бишь запрос не успел выполниться) и соотвественно, ничего не выводится из-за ошибки. Если же я закомментирую данные из props (те, которые хранятся в state), дам компоненту загрузиться и снова их раскомментирую, то все отлично выводится. Подскажите, откуда берется такое странное поведение, ведь я использую хук useEffect, который должен был выполнить запрос только после загрузки компонента?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш первый useEffect  срабатывает сразу при создании компонента, попробуйте создать второй useEffect  который срабатывае когда пришли/обновились ваши данные

```
useEffect(() => {} [yourData])
```